# What type of object does PHP's `mysqli_connect()` return?

Tags: php, mysqli

According to the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php), `mysqli_connect()` is an alias for `mysqli::__construct()`.  According to the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php) for that function, it returns

> an object which represents the connection to a MySQL Server

What is this object?  For instance, if I were relying solely on the documentation, how would I know what methods are available to a variable `$res` that I've defined as

```
$res = mysqli_connect("host", "user", "password", "database");
```

?

Comment: You could look here: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_mysqli.asp. Here are all the available functions

Comment: haven't you answered your own question here? mysqli::__construct() will create an instance of mysqli. Please take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php. Also, further it might be helpful for you to dump the object with var_dump or print_r.

Comment: You could just look at the documentation. The second page you linked to has a list of every function available...

Comment: Normally the object contains the response from the db connection (depending on type of db used) as an array of info. For example when initiate a new connection and echo the response, you can get the exact message from the server using: $mysqli->connect_errno or $mysqli->connect_error or other depending on db you are using and you are connecting. If you want a full list of all this information you can dump the object and see all the info. here is the full list: http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php as @Cooshal mention.

Answer (score 5):

I apologize if I've misunderstood, but it seems that in order for you to have needed to ask this question, you may be missing some general understanding of what a `__construct()` method does.

Any time you see an `x::__construct()` method, the object that's going to be returned is an `x`. That notation is read as `class::method()`, where the name on the right side of the `::` is a method belonging to the class named on the left side. In this case `__construct()` is a [magic method](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) called a [constructor](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php#object.construct) that is automatically called whenever you create a new instance of a class. You're not generally going to call `__construct()` directly, it will just be invoked when you make the new object.

Both of these statements are generally equivalent.

```
$res = mysqli_connect("host", "user", "password", "database");

// this calls mysqli::__construct()
$mysqli = new mysqli("host", "user", "password", "database");
```

They'll both return a `mysqli` object.

---

In terms of the relying on the documentation, when you follow that link to that [`mysqli::__construct()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php) page, it shows function definitions for both `mysqli::construct` and `mysqli_connect`. Under "procedural style", you see

```
mysqli mysqli_connect ([ string $host = ...
```

That first `mysqli` you see is the return type. You can refer to [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/about.prototypes.php) to get a better understanding of how to read a function definition. Since you're already on the `mysqli::__construct` page, all the links on the right-hand side of the page are methods of `mysqli`, but you can also click the `mysqli` link in the function definition to go directly to the class page. The PHP manual is set up that way for all the built-in classes.